# Display layer on two selects

Tags: javascript, select, onchange, layer

I am trying to display layer on choices from two select fields. I did something like this:

```
$(function() {
$('select').change(function(){
    $('.layer').hide();
    $('#w' + $(this).val()).show();
}); });
```

But layers seem to be not fixed to choices, after 3 or more changes they are displayed randomly.
http://codepen.io/DaPik/pen/rWraBr

For each possible choices should be specific layer displayed.

```
First option + first option = layer 1 displayed
First + second = layer 2
Second + first = layer 3
Second + second = layer 4.
```

@EDIT
My code doesnt work properly: At very first it looks like, but if if you choose:

```
No + Cat = Layer 4
No + Dog = Layer 3
Yes + Dog = Layer 1 and then
Yes + Cat = again Layer 3
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Can you give an example of what you think is wrong and what should be the result?

Comment: Two selects with two options each. Four layers. First option + first option = layer 1; first + second = layer 2; second + first = layer 3; second + second = layer 4

Comment: Please edit question to elaborate more.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWrajQ

```
$(function() {
  showLayer('11');
  $('select').change(function(){
    $('.layer').hide();
    var shownLayer = $('#test').val() + $('#test2').val();
    showLayer(shownLayer);
  });

  function showLayer(layer){
    $('#w' + layer).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: I see what you did there, this one cant get bugged like my. Thanks!